# Custom indent function for assembly code

Tags: assembly, emacs, indentation

I want to write a custom indentation for Emacs for my assembly language. I wrote one that almost works.

In my language there are directives that start with a dot '.' (e.g. .data .text), labels that end with a ':' (e.g. msg:  x:  buffer:) and instructions (mov eax, $24). I want the directives and labels indented to the left and instructions indented by four spaces. Here is the function in elisp:

```
(defun myasm-indent-line ()
"Indent current line as myasm code"
(interactive)
(beginning-of-line)
(save-excursion
  (beginning-of-line)
  (cond ((bobp) (indent-line-to 0))
    ((looking-at "[ \t]*\\.[:alnum:]*") (indent-line-to 0))
    ((looking-at "[ \t]*[:alnum:]*:") (indent-line-to 0))
    (t (indent-line-to 4)))))
```

I tested the regular expressions in the *scratch* buffer with this code:

```
(defun foo (s)
  (cond ((string-match-p "[ \t]*\\.[:alnum:]*" s) (message "directive"))
  ((string-match-p "[ \t]*[:alnum:]*:" s) (message "label"))
  (t (message "instruction"))))
(foo ".data")        ; prints "directive"
(foo "mov eax, 13")  ; prints "instruction"
(foo "msg:")         ; prints "label"
```

The indentation is correct for directives and instructions but incorrect for the labels which are indented by four spaces.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confused about the syntax of character classes.
`[:alnum:]` represents a set of character but it's a syntax that's to be used within a character-range, not within a regular expression.
IOW you need an extra set of brackets:

```
((looking-at "[ \t]*\\.[[:alnum:]]*") (indent-line-to 0))
((looking-at "[ \t]*[[:alnum:]]*:") (indent-line-to 0))
```

This is so that you can have regexps like `[_[:upper:][:digit:]]` or `[^[:alnum:]]`.